# how are queries evaluated when using global temp view in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm trying to choose between using global temp view and using a storage
to pass data between spark applications. (more specifically between databricks notebooks)

I want to understand when exactly the query is evaluated, and how the data or query plan is passed.

Let's say I pass a dataframe between two spark applications A and B.

If the query is executed upon global temp view creation in A, how is the data passed to B? through the memory?

and if it's executed on B, does the query plan passed by A also include information and credentials on how and where to read the datasources as well?

I tried to time jobs to test this:

on A:

```
t1 =time.time()
df = spark.read.parquet(*paths)
t2 =time.time()
df = df.filter((F.col('createdate') >= F.lit(start)) & (F.col('createdate') < F.lit(end)))
t3 = time.time()
df.show()
t4 = time.time()
df.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView('testview')
t5 = time.time()
print(t2-t1, t3-t2, t4-t3, t5-t4)
```

output: 16.02s, 0.15s, 1.96s, 0.014s

on B:

```
t1 = time.time()
sqlContext.table('global_temp.testview').show()
print(time.time()-t1)
```

output:
with `show()` on A: 2.16s
without `show()` on A: 2.30s

Based on the test results, it seems nothing is executed at the moment of view creation, and only the query plan is passed.

This begs the question, when and how is the datasource `spark.read.parquet(*paths)` accessed by B?

I couldn't find any documentation on this, and I'm looking for anyone who knows for sure

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A global temp view is global across all `SparkSession`s in your Spark application. It is still a view so not materialized as anything but a description of what should happen when the view is needed (actually, when the data this view could give is needed).

In order to exchange data between separate Spark applications, you have to use external storage like a blob storage or a database.